# Stack Snippets on Safari is really bad at throwing errors

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, safari

If you run any script that contains a error in Stack Snippets, on Safari you're greeted with a generous "script error":

> [image: dozent throw typeerror]

It does work correctly, however, in Chrome:

> [image: throws a error properly]

Could you please teach Stack Snippets in Safari to [throw errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkETT.png) properly?

---

A snippet for confirming:

```js
the_bug()
```

---

I'm currently running Mac Safari 16.2 (stable, non-beta, [latest supported version for macOS 11, 12 and 13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history), although not listed [on the list of supported browsers](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/)). Doesn’t work on iPhone, iOS 16.2 either.

Comment: If the "two latest stable" rule is true, then your version is absolutely covered. I'm not sure what to make of that page anymore– every single listed version is outside that "latest two" window now. I'm not sure what the point of listing specific versions is if they're not going to be consistently updated. For reference, the latest stable version of Chrome [is v109](https://chromestatus.com/roadmap), with v110 coming any day now– 5-6 versions ahead of the latest listed one; Opera (v95) and Firefox (v109) are both 6 ahead of listed, Safari is 4 ahead. The listings only cause confusion as-is.

Comment: @zcoop98 well that makes sense; reworded my disclaimer into a mere note

Comment: @zcoop98 yep [the page SE created](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/) is utterly useless because SE staff will never have the time and people to keep it up to date. Someone should start a feature request asking to nuke that page and get back to a list that ordinary users can update.